# Cannot find module `express` | socket.io [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I went to Git Bash and typed `npm install socket.io` I found the the directory in my user folder: `C:\Users\weka\node_modules`... anyway, I dragged the `socket.io` folder into my project `www` folder because I am using `WAMP` server.

So, here's my `server.js` for testing:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('Someone connected!');
socket.on('set nickname' , function (nickname) {
socket.nickname = nickname;
console.log(nickname + ' just connected!');
});

});

app.listen(8080);
```

and I go into `cmd` and type `node C:\wamp\www\gameTest\server.js`

and I get the error that it cannot find the `module` called `express`. I thought I downloaded `socket.io`? I am a newb when it comes to GitHub.. so I probably did it wrong. :\

Help?

UPDATE: I found out I hadn't installed it. OK, I typed `npm install express` and I now I have `express` folder in my `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`express` and `socket.io` are different libraries.  Just `npm install express` from the root of your app.

Also, make sure that your `node` dependencies are in a folder called `node_modules` - that's the convention used for module resolution.  So, you should have a file structure that looks something like:

```
/some-app
    /node_modules
        /express
        /socket.io
    server.js
```

Comment: I runed the command npm install express and i still get that error,please help me

Comment: @AlirezaFallah On windows: Go to your project root folder -> Shift+Right Click -> Open command windows here -> type npm install express. A folder called node_modules should now be created, along with the express dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to run npm at the root of your project. It installs the files relative to your project which is how node.js then looks for them to resolve the filename.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should copy the `express` module folders from `C:\Users\weka\node_modules` to your project directory as : `C:\wamp\www\gameTest\node_modules`. If you do not have a folder named `'node_modules'` in your project folder, then create it first and paste those files into this folder. This method worked for me on my `windows pc`. Restart your node server and once again run the command `node C:\wamp\www\gameTest\server.js`. It should work now !!!!